# How to send UDP packet to specific UDP dst port in scapy?

Tags: scapy

I would like to send my packet to a UDP dst port number and send it through eth0 interface (if scapy handles my layer2 directly, then eth0 does not need to be given as an argument)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Using the scapy [documentation](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/doc/usage.html#sending-packets), we see that sending an UDP packet is as simple as:

```
send(IP(dst="127.0.0.1")/UDP(dport=123)/Raw(load="abc"))
```

Comment: Maybe someone else is looking for it: use `sport=RandShort()` for a random source port.